# Tomcat : How to know the deployment location of my webapplication

Tags: java, tomcat

I have looked but i can't find a correct answer. When i deploy a webapplication on tomcat how to know the path of my deployed webapplication ?

I know that by default it is http://localhost:8080/myApp. But sometime for some more complicated project it is not. So how to retrieve the exact path ? Is there some log or something somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application configuration. What type of application you are deploying on the tomcat. For example: To deploy any maven application, you can configure the final name of your application jar/war and the port in the pom.xml.